# Does Instruments work the same with Objective-C++?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, instruments, memory-leaks

I am profiling an Objective C++ program and in the responsible caller it's not showing the exact method that created the object nor the releasing point, it only shows "CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)"
the program am profiling is a game using cocos2d and most classes are C++ .mm. I know that xcode doesn't fully support Obj-C++ Is that the reason why instruments is not showing enough info??

P.S I am using Xcode 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object itself is C++, use the Allocations instrument, click the "i" and try adjusting the configuration to "Identify C++ Objects." If you're using Leaks, I recommend instead using Allocations and [Heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/). I find it much more powerful than the Leaks tool in most cases.

That said, the dispatch() method may be obscuring the information, and this may be independent of the C++; it may simply be a limitation of Instruments when diving into the dispatch(). This happens sometimes.

All *that* said, ObjC++ is not a good language to spread throughout a project. Write your low-level code in pure C++. Write your high-level code in pure ObjC. Use a thin glue layer of ObjC++ to tie them together. ObjC++ has many problems, from poor tool support to runtime performance issues compared to pure C++ or pure ObjC. It is glue; it is not substance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the whole need for Obj-C++ was to support Box2d, I think it's too late to move to a pure Obj-C design, I am trying to debug/profile the code as is, although it will be painful and slow process.

Comment: You may be interested in this post: http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-cppfinal-edition-759

Comment: This heapshot analysis is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

at last I found what was keeping the instruments from showing the actual method calls, it wasn't the Obj C++, I have renewed the Developer Membership recently and it seems like there was 2 copies of the App on my iPad, the instruments was profiling the old one every time. Jeez!